# Tkinter in python for image processing

Tags: python, tkinter

I have run into an issue and I am asking for your support. I want to create a small app that opens and read a .tif image, it calculates NDVI ( Normalized Difference Vegetation Index ), and it displays the final result on the app screen. However and despite the fact that the code runs without an error, that doesn't seems to be the case. Please take a look on my code and help me reach out to a solution. I am using python and tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
import rasterio as rs
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x700")


frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#45aaf2')

lbl_pic_path = tk.Label(frame, text='Image Path:', padx=25, pady=25,
                        font=('verdana',16), bg='#45aaf2')
lbl_show_pic = tk.Label(frame, bg='#45aaf2')
lbl_show_pic2 = tk.Label(frame, bg='#45aaf2')

entry_pic_path = tk.Entry(frame, font=('verdana',16))
btn_browse = tk.Button(frame, text='Select Image',bg='grey', fg='#ffffff',
                       font=('verdana',16))


def selectPic():
    global img
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/images", title="Select Image",
                           filetypes=( (("All files", ".*"),("TIFF files", ".tif"))))
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img = img.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    lbl_show_pic['image'] = img
    entry_pic_path.insert(0, filename)
    
    
def calcNDVI():
    global img2
    filename2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/images", title="Select Image",
                           filetypes=( (("All files", ".*"),("TIFF files", ".tif"))))
    img2 = Image.open(filename2)
    img2 = img.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    B1 = rs.read((1))
    B2 = rs.read((2))
    NDVI = (B1-B2) / (B1 + B2)
    lbl_show_pic2['image2'] = NDVI


btn_browse['command'] = selectPic

frame.pack()

lbl_pic_path.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry_pic_path.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0,20))
lbl_show_pic.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan="2")
lbl_show_pic2.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan="4")

btn_browse.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan="2", padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide your input image! Use Google Drive or Dropbox if imgur cannot handle it. Be sure to specify which channels are Red and NIR.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what a *"sup lad"* is‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about NDVI, but the help I can give is that you don't call the calcNDVI and selectPic functions.
I also see that the button doesn't have a command, so you won't be able to call any function from that button until you assign a command to it.

Answer (score 1):

`image2` attribute is giving an error. Nothings using your `calcNDVI` so it doesn't even calculate it, so I created a new button for that and there's no functionality to make the new image.

Here we read the red and nri, calculate NDVI and convert to color map using `cm` and then create an `Image` object from the NDVI array using `PIL` then store it as global var which we then use by calling the `displayPic` function.

Let me know if you have any questions or if you had something else you wanted to achieve

```py
import tkinter as tk
import rasterio as rs
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("650x650")
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#45aaf2')

lbl_pic_path = tk.Label(frame, text='Image Path:', padx=25, pady=25, font=('verdana',16), bg='#45aaf2')
lbl_show_pic = tk.Label(frame, bg='#45aaf2')
lbl_show_pic2 = tk.Label(frame, bg='#45aaf2')
entry_pic_path = tk.Entry(frame, font=('verdana',16))
btn_browse = tk.Button(frame, text='Select Image',bg='grey', fg='#ffffff', font=('verdana',16))

def selectPic():
    global img
    global ndvi_img
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/images", title="Select Image", filetypes=( (("All files", ".*"),("TIFF files", ".tif"))))
    with rs.open(filename) as src:
        red = src.read(3)
        nir = src.read(4)
        ndvi = (nir - red) / (nir + red)
        ndvi_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.gist_earth(ndvi)*255)).resize((200,200))
        
    img = Image.open(filename).resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    lbl_show_pic['image'] = img
    entry_pic_path.insert(0, filename)
    

def displayPic():
    global ndvi_img
    ndvi_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ndvi_img)
    lbl_show_pic2['image'] = ndvi_tk
    lbl_show_pic2.image = ndvi_tk

btn_browse.config(command=selectPic)
btn_ndvi = tk.Button(frame, text='Calculate NDVI',bg='grey', fg='#ffffff', font=('verdana',16), command=displayPic)

frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
lbl_pic_path.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry_pic_path.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn_browse.grid(row=0, column=2)
lbl_show_pic.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
btn_ndvi.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)
lbl_show_pic2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Everything is perfect, thank you! Please just explain me what  ' ndvi_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.gist_earth(ndvi)*255)).resize((200,200)) 'does.

Comment: So before that line we calculate the `NDVI`, the `ndvi_img` is a PIL image object. So in this we put the NDVI of the input image into a image object.  Then we create an image from the array it returns. NDVI values are mapped to the range using the colormap `cm`, then values are multiplied by 255 to scale the range and because they come out as float values we convert them to 8-bit unsigned int format using the `np.uint8`. This is needed usually because most image libraries require image data to be in that format with pixel values from 0 to 255. If this is all, you can mark this as the solution.